# Unix timestamp adding two days to current day

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, unix

Hei,

I want to add to a day wrote in a unix format a day or two. 
I use DateTime.Now converted to Unix.The idea is if the order is finished before 16:00 the order will be shipped on next working day (datetime.now)+1. If the order is finished after 16:00 the order will be shipped on (datetime.now)+2.
This will be only on working day. If is weekend next working day will be on Monday.

```
DateTime normalSF;
            MyDateTime normal = new MyDateTime();
            MyDateTime normal1 = new MyDateTime();
            date_ship_form = normal.ConvertToUnix(DateTime.Now);
            normalSF = normal1.ConvertToDate(Convert.ToInt64(date_ship_form));                
            lblDateSF.Text = ((normalSF.Day < 10) ? "0" : "") + normalSF.Day.ToString() + "/" + ((normalSF.Month < 10) ? "0" : "") + normalSF.Month.ToString() + "/" + normalSF.Year.ToString();
```

This is how I use DateTime Unix in my code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this

```
var currdate = DateTime.Now;
long myStartDate = currdate.ToTimeStamp();
var resdate = myStartDate.AddDays(2);
long finaldate = resdate.ToTimeStamp();
```

You can try to convert the Unix timestamp to DateTime like this:

```
public static DateTime myDate(double unixTime)
{
    System.DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return dt.AddSeconds(unixTime).ToLocalTime();
}
```